# How can I make this function in Jquery loop 5 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function consists in changing the background of my body when I press spacebar as you can see if the body is yellow after 5 seconds it changes to blue and if it is blue after 5 seconds it changes to red.

I want to make that function loop 5 times.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {
            function changeColor() {
                if ($('body').hasClass('yellow')) {
                    $('body').removeClass('yellow');
                    $('body').addClass('blue');
                } else if ($('body').hasClass('blue')) {
                    $('body').removeClass('blue');
                    $('body').addClass('red');
                }
            }
        }
        setInterval(changeColor, 5000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to count the number of times the interval has been executed, then call `clearInterval` once the max amount of times `n` has been met.

To avoid using global variables, creating a new method for calling your intervals is the best option:

```
function setIntervalTimes(callback, milliseconds, times)
{
    var i=0;
    var interval = window.setInterval(function()
    {
       callback();

       if ( ++i === times ) {
           window.clearInterval(interval);
       }
    }, milliseconds);
}
```

Now you can call `setInvervalTimes()` like this:

```
function changeColor() {
  // Your logic...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
      // Perform your logic 5 times in 5 second intervals
      setIntervalTimes(function () {
        changeColor();
      }, 5000, 5);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You take a counter out of the interval and function and use that:

```
var times2toggle = 5;
var toggleColor = setInterval(changeColor, 5000);

function changeColor() {
    if( times2toggle--==0 ){ clearInterval( toggleColor ); }
    $('body').toggleClass('yellow blue');
}
```

I also added the `.toggleClass()` to the function. This does what your code does, but a lot easier to read. If it starts with yellow, the toggle class will toggle yellow off and blue on.